# Testing TFS upgrade by cloning the VM?

Tags: tfs, virtual-machine

Our TFS 2017 is hosted on a virtual machine (Windows Server 2012). We are planning to upgrade the TFS to 2018. I am planning to create a clone from the VM and running the clone as a second instance with own IP, server name, etc.

I am sure that this will create a nice clone, but I am not sure if this solution is a good way to create a clone of the TFS for upgrade testing. I believe that app- and data-tier still point to the source installation.

Has anyone tried that already and can give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not clone the VM. Instead clone the TFS instance. There is a procedure to follow when you clone an instance of TFS 2017.

1. You should make [backups of TFS DBs and restore them in a different machine or VM](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2017/08/cloning-your-tfs-server-part-01-backing.html)
2. You should [restore and prepare the DBs by changing server IDs and mapping DBs](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2017/08/cloning-your-tfs-server-part-02-prepare.html) (This step is utmost important to prevent corrupting your current production TFS instance). With TFS 2018 the clone creation is made easy as the [configuration wizard will take care of change server IDs and mapping DB Steps](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2018/02/clone-2018.html).
3. [Configure the cloned instance of TFS](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2017/08/cloning-your-tfs-server-part-03.html).

Do not try to make a copy of the VM and get it up and running which will corrupt both instances of TFS.